# R can't find object to build shiny app even though it is clearly there

Tags: r, shiny

Making a simple shiny app with tabs and R keeps giving me this error "Error in navbarPage("Pandemic Statistics", overview, h1n1_panel, covid_page,  : 
  object 'HIV_panel' not found"

If you look at the code however, it is clearly there. Furthermore if I select that section and run it the app renders no problem. This is a problem because when I try to publish the app, it stops me from doing so.

```
HIV_panel <- tabPanel(
  "Countries Most Affected by HIV/AIDS",
  HIV_sidebar,
  HIV_main
)

HIV_sidebar <- sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("year", label = "Select year", choices = c(1990:2017), 
              selected = 2000),
  p("The chart illustrates the top 25 countries in the world that were most
      affected by HIV/AIDS in a given year. It gives strong insight on answering 
      'what countries were most affected by HIV/AIDS?' The most affected 
      countries were deteremined by the ones that experienced the highest death
      rates per 100,000 people in their population. A bar chart was used 
      because it uses the simple positional encoding to easily differentiate 
      the effects of HIV/AIDS between each country. By navigating throughout 
      the years, it can be noted that African countries are historically the 
      most affected by HIV/AIDS. Inferences and conculsions can be drawn from
      the discovereries made possible by this interactive chart.")
)

HIV_main <- mainPanel(
  plotlyOutput("hivchart")
)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Pandemic Statistics",
  overview,
  h1n1_panel,
  covid_page,
  HIV_panel,
  summary
)
```

Comment: `HIV_main` is not defined at the time you attempt to assign it to `HIV_panel` (line 4), therefore, `HIV_panel` fails to assign. When you later try to call it in `navbarPage` (line 31), it doesn't exist. You have not provided enough of your code for me to be sure, but you may be able to move your assignment of `HIV_main` (line 22) to the top.

Comment: Yes, this was the solution thank you! I can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I've definitely made mistakes like these. Cheers